# How to design regex pattern for number?

Tags: java, regex

I am working on regex pattern to validate input, but I am not sure how to include () and - symbols.

Description:
The input string doesn't have to be filled out. If its filled out it needs to have exactly 5 numbers and input can't start with 26. Also, input needs to accept parenthesis and dash and they can be placed in any part of the input. I accept max 10 characters

Tried:

```
(^(?!26)((\d){5}))?
```

Works only for:
- empty input
- exactly ten digit number for example 0123456789
- also it rejects if you have 26 at the beginning, for example 2651234567

Also, tried to include - and () but this pattern doesn't work at all

```
(^(?!26)(\-\(\))((\d){5}))?

Valid inputs:
(12345)--
---12)567)
12333
-1-2--3-45
(()))12345
((12345
(-)65768-
(4)1-2-35

Invalid inputs:
26123---
(26)897---
-26333----
26
26(((())
26------
26--345
26)88-76
267-9
```

I found discussion [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?lq=1) and it helped but I still can't match exactly my entry.

Comment: So max length is 10 characters but only `5` of those can be numbers? But you state about validating phone numbers, which are more that `5` numbers? I'm confused.

Comment: @hwnd Yes. Accepts max 10 characters and 5 of them need to be numbers

Comment: Well if you are accepting 10 characters, can all those characters be numbers? Can you provide `valid` and `invalid` examples?

Comment: @hwnd it needs to have exactly 5 digits. I included invalid and valid examples. By saying that it doesn't start with 26 I also mean it doesn't start like (26) or -26--

Comment: Try the following: `^(?!([()-]*)2\1*6)(?:[()-]*\d){5}[()-]*$`

Comment: I tried your version too but it didn't work out. It was kind of close but I don't know where is the error. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a Java flavor regex. The correct regex pattern would be:

`^(?!26)([-()]*\d){5}[-()]*$`

This one will make it so your input cannot start with 26. However, your post did not specify if it could be something like --2)6-218 (it doesn't start with 26, however the first two digits are 26. If this were the case, then you would need:

`^(?![-()]*2[-()]*6)([-()]*\d){5}[-()]*$`

The 10 character max should be validated on the input, `maxlength=10`.

**Edit:** as @zx81 pointed out, I had a few unnecessary escapes. I don't know what I was thinking, sorry. However, this regex pattern does not accept empty strings.

Comment: Thank you for good suggestions. It worked I only made one small challenge and added parenthesis, moved $ sign outside of parentheses and added ? at the end since input is not required.  <f:validateRegex pattern="(^(?![\-\(\)]*2[\-\(\)]*6)(([\-\(\)]*\d){5}[\-\(\)]*)$)?"> </f:validateRegex>

Comment: Among several problems with this regex, it doesn't enforce the 10-char maximum.

Comment: @zx81 I included maxlength=10 in the <inputText> and I can't input more than 10 characters. So it works for me. I tested it. What is the problem with the regex.

Comment: @zx81 I see. My apology in the original post I wrote that it rejects if the input is 555. I meant that it should reject if at the beginning of the number is 26. Anyway, you catched that in your regex pattern. Very good job!!!

Comment: @user1282256 `What is the problem with the regex` Which one?... The first, the second, or the one you modified? Tell me which one you're planning to use, I'll tell you the problems (if any remain.)

Comment: @zx81 <f:validateRegex pattern="(^(?![\-()]*2[\-()]*6)(([\-()]*\d){5}[\-()]*)$)?"> </f:validateRegex>

Comment: @user1282256 The `?` means you would accept an empty string. Apart from that, and the fact that it requires a second validation to check the length... And some unneeded escapes, as in `-`..., and some unneeded capture groups... It can work! :)

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do what you want (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/mA6oF2)):

```
^(?!\D*(?:26|555))(?=(?:\D*\d){5}\D*$)[\d()-]{5,10}$
```

If you no longer want to reject `555`, you can go with:

```
^(?!\D*26)(?=(?:\D*\d){5}\D*$)[\d()-]{5,10}$
```

And if `2--6123` is not allowed, change the regex to

`^(?!\D*2[()-]*6)(?=(?:\D*\d){5}\D*$)[\d()-]{5,10}$`

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
(?!                      # look ahead to see if there is not:
  \D*                    #   non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
  (?:                    #   group, but do not capture:
    26                   #     '26'
   |                     #    OR
    555                  #     '555'
  )                      #   end of grouping
)                        # end of look-ahead
(?=                      # look ahead to see if there is:
  (?:                    #   group, but do not capture (5 times):
    \D*                  #     non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more
                         #     times (matching the most amount
                         #     possible))
    \d                   #     digits (0-9)
  ){5}                   #   end of grouping
  \D*                    #   non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
  $                      #   before an optional \n, and the end of
                         #   the string
)                        # end of look-ahead
[\d()-]{5,10}            # any character of: digits (0-9), '(', ')',
                         # '-' (between 5 and 10 times (matching the
                         # most amount possible))
$                        # before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         # string
```

Comment: You still want to reject `555` at the beginning, right? Anyhow, please see the demo and let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: If you want to allow `555`, see second option I just added. What about `2--6123`, is that allowed? If not, change the regex to `^(?!\D*2[()-]*6)(?=(?:\D*\d){5}\D*$)[\d()-]{5,10}$`